# The confused and problem about the jquery ajax using

Tags: ajax, jquery

At first I want request a whole page:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "Test.aspx",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (html) {
                 $(html).appendTo($("#contain"));
            },
     });
```

the whole page element will append to the div#contain,include the css,js script effect ,

but when I request part of the page 's elements,like :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "Test.aspx",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html) {
             $(html).find("div.test").appendTo($("#contain"));
        },
 });
```

the resault is that div#conntain only get the element's pure inner html,like some text,without any css or js effect……

so how can I get parts of the page 's element' include css and js effect?or it is just impossible……

Comment: Is it possible for you to define CSS,JS globally, instead into Test.aspx?. If yes then automatically part of your page element'll have CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I still don't konw why the situation would happened,but the comment above is right,if I define CSS and JS globally,this could be solved more or less ,the CSS could work ,but the js seems still not……